# Java Generics: Returning object of generic class with type parameter that is a super of argument T

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to accomplish something with Java generics and am having a hell of a time since the approaches I would instinctively take do not work in this language, due to type erasure.  I can cobble something reasonable together, though, if I get get the following to work.  I have two classes:

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}
```

And a third class:

```
class C<T extends A> {}
```

I want a generic factory method that will return an instance of `C`, if I give it an instance of either `A` or `B`.  A first attempt might look like this:

```
<T extends A> C<T> getObject(T t) { ... }
```

The issue I am having, which I suppose is not very unique, is most easily explained with the following line:

```
B b = new B();
C<A> = getObject(b);
```

The way I have defined getObject, the above call will return an object of type `C<B>`, which is not `C<A>` and does not inherit from `C<A>`, so this will not compile.

What I want to know is: is it possible to invoke some generics magic so that the compiler chooses the generic type `T` in `getObject` to be the superclass involved in the above function call, namely A?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Then why not just get rid of generics, and have `A` as parameter type, and `C<A>` as return type. Is there any other reason to make that method generic? Basically why you want it to always return `C<A>`?

Comment: `b` is of type `B` which is a sub class of `A`. In this case, type inference will bind to the type of the LHS of the assignment since `b` can be used as an `A`. You can explicitly set the type argument if you want `<B>getObject(b)`

Comment: This has nothing to do with type erasure FYI.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis just to clarify - `<A>getObject(b)` solves the problem. You should write the answer :).

Comment: @PavelHoral I would but I'm not exactly sure that's what they are looking for.

Comment: `getObject((A)b);` also solves the compilation error. Also `C<? extends A>`. But I guess I don't really understand what the issue is here. I am wondering the same thing as @RohitJain which is what the point of the generic is if you are going to want `C<A>` for a `B`.

Comment: @PavelHoral, yeah I know. Sorry, I didn't express myself clearly.  I meant to explain briefly that the rest of my code would have been easier to design (and this issue might not have come up) if type erasure weren't getting in my way.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This is precisely what I was looking for.  Thank you very much.  I didn't know you could explicitly supply generic parameters to function calls in this way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is change the declaration to be like this:

```
// (I've deviated from Java generic naming convention for clarity)
<TRet extends A, TArg extends TRet> C<TRet> getObject(TArg arg) { ... }
```

So now the return type and argument type are inferred independently:

- `TRet` is inferred based on the assignment type of the return value.
- `TArg` is inferred based on the type of the argument.

But `TArg` still must be `TRet` or a subclass of `TRet`. (Or looking at it in the other direction, `TRet` must be `TArg` or a superclass of `TArg`.)

Though I think that is a bit of an ordeal. Too, it's already been mentioned in comments that the singular-typed version compiles on Java 8.

But this:

> I can cobble something reasonable together, though, if I get get the following to work.

kind of makes me wonder. It seems like you've [described an attempted solution but not the actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and it makes me wonder if our suggestions are actually helpful here. If they are, excellent, but if they aren't, don't hesitate to edit the OP or comment with clarification.

Comment: I've tried that, actually.  It seems that the compiler still regards TArg as just plain 'ol TRet, without trying to infer from the expected return value (the LHS of the equal expression) type.

Comment: What version of Java are you compiling on? Given the simple example, this definitely compiles as of version 6. [Here it is on Ideone](http://ideone.com/IIEJ5A) which is version 7.

Comment: wow, you are 100% correct.  I am shocked; IntelliJ tells me it is wrong; it proclaims it quite loudly.  But when I try to compile the code, it works like a charm.  I am running a slightly old version; I will update and see if it is still going on.

Comment: isn't this just the same as `<TRet extends A> C<TRet> getObject(TRet arg) { ... }`?

Comment: @newacct No, because this lets the compiler infer the two types separately. The argument can be a subclass of the return value's type without supplying a witness or an upcast.

Comment: @Radiodef: But upcasts are implicit; you shouldn't need to supply anything. Perhaps this is a problem caused by limited inference.

Answer (score 1):

I am going ahead and "steal the answer" (see question comments :)).

There is nothing wrong with your class definition. Sometimes you just need to give a hint to the compiler to help it with type inference (guessing what it type should be substituted instead of the generic parameter) when calling a generic method:

```
public class Test {

    static class A { }
    static class B extends A { }
    static class C<T extends A> { }

    public static <T extends A> C<T> getObject(T obj) {
        return null; // We don't need to construct anything here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This compiles just fine
        C<A> result1 = Test.<A>getObject(new B());
        // Of course you can just type-cast the argument
        C<A> result2 = Test.getObject((A) new B());
    }

}
```

**UPDATE** (again, credits to Sotirios) Java 8 clearly has an improved generic type inference and your code would work without the explicit parameter specification as shown above (i.e. `C<A> result = getObject(new B());` would simply work *out of the box*).

Comment: I think they want it not to compile. So `<B>`.

Comment: Check the last sentence in the question: *"Is it possible to invoke some generics magic so that the compiler chooses the generic type T in getObject to be the superclass involved in the above function call, namely A?"*

Comment: Then I'm still missing the point because `C<A> result = getObject(new B());` works fine.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `C<A> result = getObject(new B());` actually does not work (at least not in Eclipse / JDK 7).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It won't work. The type will be inferred as `B`, and it would return `C<B>`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so one of possible answers might be for the OP to switch to Java 8.

Comment: Aside from explicitly specifying the type argument as in `C<A> c = Test.<A>getObject(new B())`, you can also force the type variable to be inferred as `A` simply by changing the type of the call argument to `A`, e.g., with a cast: `C<A> c = Test.getObject((A)new B())`.